# Use only local maven repository for needed jars

Tags: maven-2

Is it possible to first download jars needed to orgnisation local maven repository and then to machine repository to use.

my scenario is:

1.My project is using abc.jar and it is not exist on my local repository then I want it to download from public repository to orgnisation local maven repository first.

2.And then my project will use this abc.jar from orgnisation local maven repository.

is it possible or I want to deploy manually each jar to orgnisation local maven repository.

Because right now if my project need any jar then it finds it on local maven repository if not found then download it directly to my local machine ~/.m2/repository folder. I want to download first to orgnisation local repository and then my local machine.
Now my Settings.xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>

  <server>
      <id>local.orgnisation.repo</id>
      <username>pallavi</username>
      <password>pallavi</password>
    </server>
    </servers>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>local.orgnisation.repo</id>
      <name>Local repository</name>
      <url>http://local.orgnisation.repo/artifactory/repo</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

<!--<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>local.orgnisation.repo</id>
              <url>http://local.orgnisation.repo/artifactory/repo</url>
          </repository>
      </repositories>
        </profile>
  </profiles>-->
    <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

I am using artifactory repository manager.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: run in terminal/ command mvn dependency:resolve on the directory having pom.xml with all dependency mentioned.

Comment: but it will download from maven to my local machine rather than on my orgnisation local repository. I want to download first to company local repository and then to local to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mirror entry in your Maven settings.xml for the central repository

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

```
<mirror>
  <id>local</id>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  <url>URL of your artifactory repository</url>
</mirror>
```

Comment: I have added creadentials to use the organisation repository in my settings.xml so its giving me problem when I add <mirror> and its giving unauthorizwd access to maven resources plugin

Comment: @pallavi Can you give more information. What type of issue are you getting?

Comment: Failed to transfer org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-resources-plugin from http://local.orgnisation.repo/artifactory was cached in local repository resolution will not be reattempted untill the update interval of local has elapsed or updates are forced. Access denied to  http://local.orgnisation.repo/artifactory but I am providing the creadentials to access local repo.

Comment: I have added my setting.xml file please have a look.

Comment: @pallavi I suggest you remove the authentication requirement from the repository until you get the proxying working. The authentication setup looks correct.

Comment: I removed the authentication and its working. :) To work with authentication I have just added admin credentials instead of normal user.